# Error With Android SDK in Linux Unity5.4.0f3

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, unity-game-engine

Installed unity5.4.0.f (deb file), download from [https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/#post-2648924], While taking build i am getting the below error.

FYI, we are having problem to install higher versions of unity from 5.3 onwards in ubuntu using PlayOnLinux. While searching for alternatives, i came across this Linux unity and i spent some quality time but still no good.
Any possible aiding answers are welcome.Thanks in advance.

Getting this Error:-

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='/home/mohan/Documents/UnityStuff/sdk/tools/aapt', CommandLine='package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "/home/mohan/Documents/UnityStuff/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_', CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
UnityEditor.Utils.Program.Start () (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Utils/Program.cs:33)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.TasksCommon.Exec (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.CompileResources (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildResources.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at /home/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:176)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```